# QTableView, QTableWidget and QStandardItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

Is it possible to some how set a `QStandardItemModel` as a model to `QTableWidget`? I currently have managed to put a `QStandardItemModel` in a `QTableView`, but I can't find any SIGNAL options to detect the selected items as I have to select either single or multiple item from the `QTableView`. My code snippet that is responsible to fill `QTableView` is as the following:

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(tableRow, 3, this);
QPixmap pMap = QPixmap::fromImage(image, Qt::AutoColor);
QStandardItem * itm = new QStandardItem;
itm->setIcon(pMap);
model->setItem(rowPointer, columnPointer, itm);
ui->listOfImages->setModel(model);
```

Here `ui->listOfImages` is the `QTableView`.

Is there any way either to make `QTableWidget` work with `QStandarItemModel` or to get  the signals from `QTableView`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are the [`QAbstractItemView` signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#signals), but for selection, there is separate [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel), which has the [signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html#signals) you probably want.

`QXxxxWidget` classes are convenience wrappers around a `QXxxxxView` and custom model which bring all this into simpler package, at the cost of flexibility. If you want to specify model, you have to use the `QXxxxView`, and do a bit more plumbing yourself, no way around that as far as I know.